# Swap partition not enabled after booting up

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, gparted, swap

This is what my gparted looks like [image: image of my gparted partition table]

When i formatted my computer before installing Ubuntu, I set up the partitions properly (or so i thought) and had the last "unknown" area as a linux-swap and turned it on. I've installed it and it went smoothly. Then I booted up and saw this. I've booted to a live USB drive and formatted that unknown area, and successfully set up a linux-swap and turned it on twice, and both times it reverted back to this in gparted.

This is what I get when I run `sudo blkid`

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="2152-B1BC" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="593f856a-b25e-4f25-ac48-3c5b00dcf7d9" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda3: UUID="78b1b1a0-b721-4f52-8b17-b577bd573225" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1: UUID="9b33ee92-f21f-4e07-b080-95ef59a62d1d" TYPE="swap"
```

This is the result of running `cat /etc/fstab`

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=593f856a-b25e-4f25-ac48-3c5b00dcf7d9 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=2152-B1BC  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=78b1b1a0-b721-4f52-8b17-b577bd573225 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda4 during installation
#UUID=7c51619a-5ead-4e78-af2d-2900f3b4046c none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

this is what i get when i run free -h

> ```
>         total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
> ```
>
> Mem:          5.0G       4.8G       126M         0B        11M       3.6G
>   -/+ buffers/cache:       1.2G       3.8G
>   Swap:          18G       200M        18G

(sorry for making you edit this post again i can't figure out the formatting here yet)

Comment: I think that that's the right result that Gparted should show when dealing with encrypted partitions (like your encripted swap).

Please add to your question the output of `free -h`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you have used encryption for your home folder. For security reasons, when you encrypt your home folder, the swap is also encrypted. Therefore, GPartEd is unable to see the contents of the partition.

The partition is accessed through the encryption application. The key line in your `fstab` is this:

`/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0`

You can also see it from `blkid`:

`/dev/mapper/cryptswap1: UUID="9b33ee92-f21f-4e07-b080-95ef59a62d1d" TYPE="swap"`

It shows that `cryptswap` is going to load your swap partition. To check, open System Monitor and go to the Resources tab. Under the graph for Memory and Swap History, you'll see the Swap showing the amount available and the amount used. If the amount available is not zero, your swap is working fine.

[image: Swap being shown in System Monitor > Resources]